# Traefik configuration issue with local proxy

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Edit: I have updated my configuration to reflect [Henrik Hoegh's tutorial](https://www.praqma.com/stories/Proxying-Docker-containers-with-ease/). I am still running into issues.

I am setting up a local development environment with lots of docker containers running applications. I am using Traefik to manage and locally proxy these containers (each container having a named local URL). Right now my setup is as follows

**Traefik.toml**

```
[web]
  address = ":8088"
  [web.statistics]

################################################################
# Docker configuration backend
################################################################
[docker]

endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "local.io"
watch = true

# Expose containers by default in traefik
exposedbydefault = true

# Use the IP address from the bound port instead of the inner network one. For specific use-case :)
usebindportip = true

# Use Swarm Mode services as data provider
swarmmode = false
```

Docker-compose.yml file for container

```
... 
container_name: mcserviceface
labels:
  - "traefik.port=8080"
...
```

I also have added `local.io` and `mcserviceface.local.io` (both pointing to my local machine) to my `ect/hosts` file.

When I start up the Traefik container and the mcserviceface container, it shows up on the Traefik dashboard, but it does not show the URL as `mcserviceface.local.io` rather something like `http://185.28.0.3:80`. I also hit a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` when I follow that link.

How do I resolve both of these issues?

Edit: I have made sure that both containers on are on the same docker network via `docker network connect ...`. It does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Do not use `docker network connect` for this, instead the container should join the network as part of it's creation, preferably inside the compose file. And you'll also want to pass the `traefik.docker.network` label to specify which network if the container is on more than one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you connect your traefik instance to the client docker-network (as specified on the bottom of [this page](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/)):

```
When running inside a container, Træfik will need network access through:

docker network connect <network> <traefik-container>
```

Comment: I have updated my question, in particular the issue does not seem to be based on network connection.